# Unable to identify colours on leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

```
var non_tfl_lines_JubileetoIlford = L.geoJson(non_tfl_lines_JubileetoIlford, {
     pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        switch (feature.geometry.type) {
          case 'LineString': return new L.polyline(latlng, {
            color: feature.properties.color
          });
          case 'Point':   return new L.Circle(latlng, 400, {
            color: getColor(feature.properties.relief_JtI)});
        }
        onEachFeature: popup
     }
}).addTo(map);
```

For some reason the colour of the polyline is the default colour and not the one specified. In same time it gives me the correct colours of the circles. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson), **pointToLayer** callback is for GeoJSON points; this is why your code works for points.

If you want to set the color with information from your geojson structure, the best is to have a color property ...

```
   {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
          "color": "#ff7800"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
```

And use it in the **style** callback

```
L.geoJson(non_tfl_lines_JubileetoIlford, {
    style: function(feature) {
        if(feature.geometry.type == "LineString") {
           return {
                   "color": feature.properties.color,
                   "weight": 5,
                   "opacity": 0.65
               };
        }
    }
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/myxd1ooy/

Comment: Still have a problem. I have posted it as an answer cause it is to long for a comment.

Comment: style will be called for all layers (including points). You can return a style only for LineString (see updated answer).

Comment: How about the new one posted?